# Tkinter error: bad window path name when deleting frames dynamically

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Im trying to recreate a little version of trello in tkinter. Right now im stuck I have a problem when I want to delete frames in a different order. For example: I click on the button and a new frame is generated if I delete that everything works. If I create 3 frames I have to remove them in the same order as I have created them. So I think my problems lies in the pop function but I dont know how to access them manually. When i change the pop function to (1) then I have to delete the second creation first instead of the first.
Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Window:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.root.geometry(width + "x" + height)

class Frames:
    def __init__(self):
        self.l = Frame(window.root, bg="red", height=300, width=300, relief="sunken")
        self.l.place(relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.3)
        self.deleteB = Button(self.l, text="X", command=self.delete_frame, bg="blue")
        self.deleteB.place(rely=0, relx=0.92)
        self.addB = Button(self.l, text="Add", command=self.add_note, bg="blue")
        self.addB.place(rely=0, relx=0.65)

    def delete_frame(self):
        self.l.pack()
        self.l.pack_forget()
        self.l.destroy()
        frames.pop()

    def add_note(self):
        self.note_Label = Label(self.l, text="Clean the room")
        self.note_Label.pack(padx=20, pady=10)
        self.delete_Note = Button(self.note_Label, text="X", command=self.del_Note)
        self.delete_Note.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

    def del_Note(self):
        self.note_Label.pack_forget()
        self.note_Label.destroy()

class Note:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class DragNDrop:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def make_draggable(self, widget):
        widget.bind("<Button-1>", self.on_drag_start)
        widget.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.on_drag_motion)

    def on_drag_start(self, event):
        widget = event.widget
        widget._drag_start_x = event.x
        widget._drag_start_y = event.y

    def on_drag_motion(self, event):
        widget = event.widget
        x = widget.winfo_x() - widget._drag_start_x + event.x
        y = widget.winfo_y() - widget._drag_start_y + event.y
        widget.place(x=x, y=y)


class Buttons:
    def __init__(self):
        self.button = Button(window.root, width=20, height=20, bg="blue", command=self.add_frames)
        self.button.pack()

    def add_frames(self):
        frames.append(Frames())
        print(frames)


window = Window("800", "600")
frames = []

drag = DragNDrop()

button = Buttons()

while True:
    for i in frames:
        drag.make_draggable(i.l)
    window.root.update()
```

If someone has an Idea or workaround that would be nice to know.
Also I have another Idea instead of destroying them I could just hide them but in the end that makes the programm really slow at some point.

Here is the error: _tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!frame2"

Comment: Post the error you get

Comment: Here: _tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!frame2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code needs to remove the frame from the list. Instead, you're calling `pop` which always removes the last item. That causes you to lose the reference to the last window, and one of the references in `frames` now points to a window that has been deleted (which is the root cause of the error)

Instead, call `remove`:

```
def delete_frame(self):
    self.l.destroy()
    frames.remove(self)
```